# Dinghy Racing: how do I use the kicker/vang properly?

Tags: sailing

I'm sailing an [Enterprise Dinghy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_(dinghy)), and recently upgraded to a cascading kicker (kicking strap, boom vang, ...). The previous kicker I had I could never operate during a race properly, but now I can, and my question is: **what is the best way to learn how to use a kicker properly?**

I know that in very light wind it should be tight to flatten the sail, making it easier for the weak wind stream to attach to the sail, off in medium wind which has more power to pull the rounder sail forward, and tight again in strong wind to depower the sail. But how do I go beyond that? How can I best learn to match a sail shape to the wind condition, and then achieve that shape with the kicker?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't involve a *competitive* sport. Please edit to focus the question on the competitive aspects, or consider deleting this and reposting on [The Great Outdoors](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @PhilipKendall On the contrary, it is very competitive. Using the kicker properly is essential for dinghy racing, in order to achieve the best boat speed in given conditions. I have sailed recreationally for many years without using the kicker, as it is not essential for cruising.

Comment: Good running technique isn't essential for recreational jogging, that doesn't mean a question on good technique is about competitive running. Same deal with your kicker technique and recreational versus competitive sailing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to learn how to use a boom vang is really by using it, but here are some guidelines that I have taught at Sailing Schools, and used to great effect when racing:

- in very light wind, you actually don't want tension on it at all

But if you have a large swell or rough seas in a light wind, leaving the vang too loose will let your boom bounce up and down, so pull it in enough to stop that happening.

- in high winds you want it pulled in tight

This gives more power, as the sail flattens, and the mast bends, but be ready to slacken it off as the sail overpowers.

That basic rule, having your vang tension proportional to the wind strength is an excellent approximation. This allows the sail more power - which is what you want control of in racing.

It would be ideal if the helmsman could also work the vang, because you can play the helm, main sheets and vang off against each other, but on a 2 person boat you'd usually have your crew play the vang.

Edit: Just found a [brief page from Dave Dellenbaugh](http://www.sailingbreezes.com/sailing_breezes_current/articles/Aug00/dell0800.htm) (an America's Cup veteran) that gives a little more detail on these.